# How can I compute |R/I| where $R\simeq\mathbb Z^n$ and $I\unlhd R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

A number field $K$ is a field $\mathbb Q\le K\le\mathbb C$ of finite degree over $\mathbb Q$, say $n$.

Call $\mathbb A$ the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb C$; an algebraic integer is an $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ which is a root of some monic polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$.

Then the number ring associated to $K$ is $R:=\mathbb A\cap K$. We know that it's a free abelian group of rank $n$, i.e. $R\simeq\mathbb Z^{n}\simeq\underbrace{\mathbb Z\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb Z}_{n}$.

Given an ideal of $R$, call it $I$, how can I interpretate $R/I$ in terms of $\mathbb Z$? I know that's vague. I'll give an example, in order to be clearer.

If $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]=\mathbb A\cap\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-5}]$, it's $R\simeq\mathbb Z^2$. Given the ideal $I=(2)=2R\unlhd R$, I read that $|R/(2)|=4$ and the only idea to explain this to me is to think $R/(2)$ as
$$
\mathbb Z/(2)\oplus\mathbb Z/(2)
$$
where now $(2)$ is understood to be $2\mathbb Z$, an ideal of $\mathbb Z$. Hence , being $|\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z|=2$ I thought that something like $|R/(2)|=|\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z|=|\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z|^2=2^2$ could work.

But I'm aware that this is not precise as it should.

How can I do if for example $R=\mathbb Z[i]$ and $I=(1-i)$? How can I compute $|R/I|$ in this case?

Thank you all

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for? This is generally a hard problem. By CRT you can reduce to the case that $I=\mathfrak{p}$ a prime. Then, you're essentially trying to determine the 'inertial degree' of $\mathfrak{p}$ over $\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$. In some cases, as in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ this is somewhat easy. For example, your $I$ is prime, and the prime it lies over is $2$. So factoring the min poly of $i$, namely $x^2+1$, then factor it in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. It factors $(x-1)^2$. Then, since $I$ is the prime associated to the factor $(x-1)$, you know that $R/I$ as an $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: vector space has dimension $2$. I am using what's called the 'Dedekind-Kummer theorem' here. It applies whenever $K$ is monogenic (i.e. whenever $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}$)--and you can actually extend it if you work harder.